# Is there a way to crop a large image on android without loading into memory?

Tags: android, image, memory, sd-card, crop

I don't want to display the bitmap on the screen. Just trying to create a max square image out of the original image from sdcard and then uploading to server. Is there a way to crop an image without loading the image into memory? or load the image in chunks and then save to file?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to cut an image into "tiles" and send each tile to the server?

Comment: No, I just want one cropped image out of the original image. let say if the original image is 200 x 300. Cropped image should be 200 x200. if the original image is already square then cropping is not needed

Comment: Do you want the user to select what to be cropped or just crop it?

Comment: I think Litus answered it, thanks anyway  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well the question but this could help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

BitmapRegionDecoder can be used to decode a rectangle region from an image. BitmapRegionDecoder is particularly useful when an original image is large and you only need parts of the image.

Hope to help :)

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick but only 2.3.3 and above. I guess I need to download BitmapRegionDecoder code from git and use within the app to support below level 10

Comment: If you succed I wish you share. This property is very useful

Comment: It uses native APIs. Doubt it can be ported easily.

Comment: yes wasn't able to do it at least I tried. I am not very good with native stuff so given up